# Same index in Pandas Dataframe, delete NaN rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

How can I get the data from this dataframe into 2 rows only, deleting the NaN? (I concated 3 different Dataframes into a new one, showing averages from another Dataframe)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J48ww.png)

This is what i want to achieve:

```
0 Bitcoin (BTC) 36568.673315   5711.3.059220.      1.229602e+06
1 Ethereum (ETH) 2550.870272   670225.756425       8.806719e+05
```

It can either be in a new dataframe or using the old one. Thank you so much for ur help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.bfill(axis ='rows', inplace=True) # filling the missing values
df.dropna(inplace=True) # drop rows with Nulls
```